# ModuleNotFoundError after successful pip install

Tags: python, pypi, modulenotfounderror

I have a problem with a package that I just created and that I want to upload on PyPi. The structure of the package is as follows:

```
|- setup.py
|- README.md
|- alexandria (root folder for the package)
  |- __init__.py
  |- many sub-packages
```

the setup.py specifies the name of the package to be "alexandria-python". I wish I can call it "alexandria", but the name is already reserved on PyPi.
When I first install the package locally, with "pip install -e .", it works fine. I can open Spyder or Jupyter from Anaconda, use "import alexandria", no error is returned.
I can also import and use any of the sub-packages without problems.

So I then moved on uploading the package on test-Pypi. It worked fine, the package can be found at:
https://test.pypi.org/project/alexandria-python/

I try to install it on my computer, using pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ alexandria-python
The install seems to work ("Successfully installed alexandria-python-0.0.1"), but when I open Spyder/Jupyter and try "import alexandria", I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/tmp/ipykernel_24757/3637483902.py", line 1, in 
import alexandria

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alexandria'

This is all the more strange since the package is found in the conda environment. Using the command "conda list" for instance yields:

packages in environment at /home/romain/installs/anaconda3:

Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py39h06a4308_0
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
alexandria-python         0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi

So the package is found.

In the end, I don't understand what can be the source of the error: problem of package structure, python path... Has anyone an idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't uploaded your actual package code to PyPi.

If you go here [to your PyPi downloads page](https://test.pypi.org/project/alexandria-python/#files) and then download the source distribution, you will see that it contains your `.egg-info` file but not you code.

Make sure your archive file has everything it needs before uploading to PyPi.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer! Sounds indeed better to add the code when uploading. What I don't get is how I possibly obtained a source distribution without the code, since I followed standard procedures. I will check all that and update the post.

Comment: thanks again for your comment. So the issue is effectively that the code is not included. So I tried to recreate the archive. Specifically, I open a terminal, move to the root folder of the package (the one containing  the setup.py and README.md files along with the alexandria folder - the one of interest containing my package - . Then I use the command python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel, which seems to be the correct command, from all the tutorials I read. The archive seems to be created correctly.

Comment: But when I open the newly created sdist folder and unzip the alexandria-python-0.0.2.tar.gz file, it does not contain the alexandria folder. The readme.md and the setup.py from the root folder are there, but the alexandria folder with the package has been omitted/removed. That does not make any sense. Has anyone ever faced this?