# "ModuleNotFoundError" after installing a python package

Tags: python, pip, package

## Problem summary

I am very new to python package development. I developed a package and [published it at TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/spark-map/). I install this package trough `pip` with no errors. However, python is giving me a "ModuleNotFoundError" when I try to import it, and I have no idea why. Can someone help me?

## Repro steps

First, I install the package with:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ spark-map==0.2.76
```

Then, I open a new terminal, start the python interpreter, and try to import this package, but python gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```py
>>> import spark_map
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spark_map'
```

## What I discover

- When I `cd` to the root folder of the package, and open the python interpreter, and run `import spark_map`, it works fine with no errors;
- That `pip` did not installed the package succesfully; However I checked this. I got no error messages when I install the package, and when I run `pip list` after the `pip install` command, I see `spark_map` on the list of installed packages.

```bash
> pip list
... many packages
spark-map                0.2.76
... more packages
```

- The folder where `spark_map` was installed can be out of the module search path of Python; I checked this as well. `pip` is installing the package on a folder called `Python310\lib\site-packages`, and this folder is included inside the `sys.path` variable:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path:
...     print(path)

C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

## Information about the system

I am on Windows 10, Python 3.10.9, trying to install and import the `spark_map` package, version 0.2.76.(https://test.pypi.org/project/spark-map/).

## Information about the code

[The package source code is hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/pedropark99/spark_map), and the folder structure of this package is essentially this:

```
root
│
├───spark_map
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───functions.py
│   └───mapping.py
│
├───tests
│   ├───functions
│   └───mapping
│
├───.gitignore
├───LICENSE
├───pyproject.toml
├───README.md
└───README.rst
```

The `pyproject.toml` file of the package:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "toml"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "spark_map"
version = "0.2.76"
authors = [
  { name="Pedro Faria", email="pedropark99@gmail.com" }
]
description = "Pyspark implementation of `map()` function for spark DataFrames"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
license = { file = "LICENSE.txt" }
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

dependencies = [
    "pyspark",
    "setuptools",
    "toml"
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://pedropark99.github.io/spark_map/"
Repo = "https://github.com/pedropark99/spark_map"
Issues = "https://github.com/pedropark99/spark_map/issues"


[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "."
]


[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []
```

## What I tried

As @Dorian Turba suggested, I moved the source code into a `src` folder. Now, the structure of the package is this:

```
root
├───src
│   └───spark_map
│       ├───__init__.py
│       ├───functions.py
│       └───mapping.py
│
├───tests
├───.gitignore
├───LICENSE
├───pyproject.toml
├───README.md
└───README.rst
```

After that, I executed `python -m pip install -e .` (the log of this command is on the image below). The package was compiled and installed succesfully. However, when I open a new terminal, in a different location, and try to run `python -c "import spark_map"`, I still get the same error.

[image]

I also tried to start a virtual environment (with `python -m venv env`), and install the package inside this virtual environment (with `pip install -e .`). Then, I executed `python -c "import spark_map"`. But the problem still remains. I executed `pip list` too, to check if the package was installed. The full log of commands is on the image below:

[image]

Comment: Should the path to the module be `root/src/spark_map` instead of just `root/spark_map`?

Comment: I am really new to this, so I do not know if this is the best way. But I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: Great details in the question, thanks a lot, if all asker could be like you, that would be great !

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611215/modulenotfounderror-after-successful-pip-install

Comment: In the `What I tried` section, can you share your new file hierarchy please?

Comment: Yes! I will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The source of the problem

The source of the problem is at the "build process" of the package. In other words, `pip install` was installing a "not valid package".

Basically, I use setuptools to build the package. When I compiled (or "build" the package with `python -m build`, the source code of the package (that is, all contents of the `src` directory), was not included in the compiled TAR archive.

### Fix using setuptools

The [documentation for setuptools talks about this issue of finding the source code for your project](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html). In essence, setuptools was not finding the source code of the package. So I needed to help him find these files, by adding these two options to my `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["spark_map"]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}
```

## How can you identify this problem ?

If you are having a similar problem at installing and importing your package, you might have this same problem, as I did. To check if that is your case, build your project with `python -m build`. Then, open the source distribution of your package (that is, the TAR archive), and check if the source code is there, inside this TAR file. If not, than, you have this exact problem.

Comment: With your added config, does a local install like pip install . works now?

Comment: This looks like a workaround to not have to put the spark_map folder in a src, which is not standard. If it works, great but I wouldn't recommend that and we should make it work with a standard package layout if possible.

Comment: Yes! When I added these `[tool.setuptools]` options, the local install with `pip install -e .` worked, and the import too!

Comment: Yeah! I found this odd too, because the best practice in the documentation you cited, was to include the package inside a src folder. So, I do not know WHY setuptools could not find the source code in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I understand why. Can you share the file tree after moving files in the src folder?

Comment: I just added this file tree to the previous question, but I will add it to this answer too!

Comment: Can you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75286445/6251742 I don't use setuptools, so this is maybe why I don't get the same result as you do

Answer (score 1):

## src folder is required

The standard file layout is the following
([Python doc: Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#a-simple-project)):

> ```
> packaging_tutorial/
> ├── LICENSE
> ├── pyproject.toml
> ├── README.md
> ├── src/
> │   └── example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/
> │       ├── __init__.py
> │       └── example.py
> └── tests/
> ```

You need to put your package inside a `src` folder.

For your project, it should look like this:

```
root
│
├───src/
│   └───spark_map/
│       ├───__init__.py
│       ├───functions.py
│       └───mapping.py
├───tests/
│   ├───functions
│   └───mapping
├───.gitignore
├───LICENSE
├───pyproject.toml
├───README.md
└───README.rst
```

You don't need to build a wheel distribution to test that, you can install the package directly to your env with `pip install .` (or in edit mode if you want your update to be directly accessible without having to reinstall `pip install -e .`).

Comment: Glad to help, I had many many issue with stuff like this, many of them was inattention to details!

Comment: I moved the spark_map folder, to a src folder, and, compiled the project again, with `python -m build --wheel`, and then, installed this wheel distribution with `pip install`. However, the problem still remains. I open a terminal somewhere, and the python interpreter, I try to run `import spark_map` and the same "ModuleNotFoundError" appears

Comment: Can you try with `pip install -e .` ?
Have you checked if you are in the correct python env? have you a virtual environment? Is it activated?

Comment: I tried this `pip install -e .` command, and I updated the question with the log info. But, the "ModuleNotFound" error still remains when I try to import it.

Comment: @pedro I don't understand why moving the project into src didn't fix your issue. The fix you find just allows you to not use the src file, but it's not standard and might be confusing. Have you moved all tree files in src, or the whole `spark_map` folder in src?

Answer (score 1):

## Use Hatchling with sources in a src folder

Change the build system to hatchling

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"
```

You also need to change the layout of your project like explained in this answer: [src folder is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284960/6251742).

Comment: I tested this solution, and it worked too! So I add this solution to my answer too!

Comment: Don't edit your answer with other answer content. Each answer is one solution, people will upvote what they think is better for the community. This way, I will be rewarded if my answer is helpful. You can still mark your own answer as the one you prefer. I edited and upvoted your answer anyway, since it works and is a great answer to people who absolutly need to use setuptool !

Answer (score 0):

## Check you use the correct Python environment

1. If you use a virtual environment, make sure [it's activated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work)
2. Make sure that the package is installed in this environment (using [`pip list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/)).